# Displaying an openni_tracker skeleton in RViz?

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, openi-tracker, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Has anyone written a node to take the skeleton produced by openni_tracker (or something similar) and display it in RViz?  I'd like to see the skeleton alongside my robot's URDF model in RViz.  I'm guessing one would have to write a node to publish RViz-style markers for each joint but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's already been done.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9572/displaying-an-openni_tracker-skeleton-in-rviz?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can turn on the tf visuzizer to see the skeleton quickly.  It would be great to have a fancier marker style visuzlization, but it works well for debugging.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-29**:
Just an update to say I wrote a little ROS package to display RViz visualization markers for the skeleton joints.  It can be found at http://www.ros.org/wiki/skeleton_markers.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-03-25**:
How cool is that!